# find maxdate and mindate when grouped

Tags: php, group-by, maxdate, mindate

DB table

```
TYPE       DATE         PLAYER   MINUTE
---------------------------------------
starter    2000-01-01   Tom      
starter    2005-01-01   Tom      
starter    2005-01-01   Ben 
starter    2010-01-01   Tom
subbedin   2012-01-01   Ben      46
```

Query

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT *,
SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'starter' OR type = 'subbedin' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS apps,
SUM(CASE WHEN Tüüp = 'starter' THEN 90 ELSE 0 end + CASE WHEN Tüüp = 'subbedin' THEN 91 - minutes ELSE 0 end) AS minutes
FROM players
GROUP BY player
ORDER BY apps DESC minutes DESC
");
```

I've grouped the results by player alongside their appearances and minutes, but I'm having trouble getting it to show the date of the first and the last appearances.

```
PLAYER   APPS   MINUTES   FIRST        LAST
-------------------------------------------------
Tom      3      270       2000-01-01   2010-01-01
Ben      2      135       2005-01-01   2012-01-01
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ....

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'starter' OR type = 'subbedin' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS apps,
    SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'starter' THEN 90 ELSE 0 end + CASE WHEN type = 'subbedin' THEN 91 - minutes ELSE 0 end) AS `minutes`,
    MIN(`DATE`) as `FIRST`,
    MAX(`DATE`) as `LAST`
    FROM players
    GROUP BY player;
```